# Is it possible to embed Google Maps into MapField or BrowserField?

Tags: google-maps, blackberry

I want to handle `onClick` events of placemarks on Google Maps. I need to get id or coordinates of clicked placemark into my application. Is it possible or can you offer me an alternative way?

Now, I just run Google Maps application:

```
 ApplicationDescriptor ad = CodeModuleManager.getApplicationDescriptors(mh)[0];
        ApplicationDescriptor ad2 = new ApplicationDescriptor(ad, args);
        try {
            ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager().runApplication(ad2, true);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't embed the Google map into your application. There was a project (that I think may be defunct) where the dev was trying to do it by manually requesting tiles and whatnot, but I haven't heard of it in a while.

You'll have to embed a MapField (make sure the BlackBerry Maps is installed) and then manually control things like navigation, zoom, and placemarks.

Comment: So, if I use Blackberry Maps, can I handle placemark click events on my application. I want to switch screen when user click to a coordinate and pass this coordinate to new screen.

Comment: You will most likely have to emulate this by creating a custom Manager that places them on the map, then watch for clicks/touches and see if they are on a placemark. After that you can control what happens.

Comment: Can you give some details about onClick events. How can I handle when clicked to a placemark? Can you suggest any docs?

Comment: I had to create a Manager for the MapField and then just do calculations and emulate the placemarks being clickable, when in reality I was just checking where the touch event was and figuring out if something should be there.

Comment: Oh, no. It is not a real Blackberry Maps you talking about. It is just a picture. Why do you call it Blackberry Maps?!

Comment: I want to embed Blackberry Maps into my application.

Comment: You can do so with the MapField. You just have to capture movements (navigation and touch) and then recenter the map. The image that gets placed there isn't actually static, there are just no controls really built into it to move it around or zoom.

Comment: That is a good news for me. So can you give me a code example about catching the clicks on markers? How can I understand when clicked to a Coordinate?

Comment: There is no way to use Google Maps with functionality of book markking,try using nutiteq,it can offer whatever you requires,Plz check Pros and cons while using it.

Answer (score 1):

I have displayed Google map in my application. Its simple. Make sure that you have installed Google map. This BlackBerry support forum thread may be useful to you:
[How to use Google Map in Blackberry Application?](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/How-to-use-Google-Map-in-Blackberry-Application/td-p/326980)